# How can I sections out of __TEXT and into a new segment for a mach-o binary?

Tags: ios, mach-o

How can I move sections out of the `__TEXT` segment and into a new segment for a mach-o binary? The reason I'm asking is that I'm trying to make my iPhone app smaller, and the iOS App Store encrypts the `__TEXT` segment of it prior to compression so that it doesn't compress at all. If I can move all the non-executable sections out of that segment and into a new read-only segment, then I can trim the size of my app by about 9%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ld`'s `-rename_section` flag does the job.

Answer (score 4):

## On linker level

As already mentioned in @meisel answer this can be done through:
[image]
So the value to set would be:

```
-Wl,-rename_section,__TEXT,__sectionName,__NEW_SEGMENT_NAME,__newSectionName
```

if segment permisions need to be adjusted

```
-segprot,__NEW_SEGMENT_NAME,rx,rx
```

Be careful with `rwx` for executable code, the app will be immediately killed by iOS XNU kernel if `rxw` running code is detected. It's still fine for x86-64 simulator. This blog [post](https://medium.com/@michael.eisel/one-trick-to-drastically-reduce-your-ios-apps-downlsize-ae68aad0d369) covers some usage examples.

## On function prototype level

Assuming you're using **Objective-C** (or **C** for that matter) you can use `__attribute__ section(...)`.
**Syntax:**
`__attribute__ ((section("segmentName,sectionName,[optional]sectionType,[optional]sectionAttribute,[optional]stubSize")))`
From https://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-137/src/lib/MC/MCSectionMachO.cpp allowed `sectionTypes`:

```
  { "regular",                  "S_REGULAR" },                    // 0x00
  { 0,                          "S_ZEROFILL" },                   // 0x01
  { "cstring_literals",         "S_CSTRING_LITERALS" },           // 0x02
  { "4byte_literals",           "S_4BYTE_LITERALS" },             // 0x03
  { "8byte_literals",           "S_8BYTE_LITERALS" },             // 0x04
  { "literal_pointers",         "S_LITERAL_POINTERS" },           // 0x05
  { "non_lazy_symbol_pointers", "S_NON_LAZY_SYMBOL_POINTERS" },   // 0x06
  { "lazy_symbol_pointers",     "S_LAZY_SYMBOL_POINTERS" },       // 0x07
  { "symbol_stubs",             "S_SYMBOL_STUBS" },               // 0x08
  { "mod_init_funcs",           "S_MOD_INIT_FUNC_POINTERS" },     // 0x09
  { "mod_term_funcs",           "S_MOD_TERM_FUNC_POINTERS" },     // 0x0A
  { "coalesced",                "S_COALESCED" },                  // 0x0B
  { 0, /*FIXME??*/              "S_GB_ZEROFILL" },                // 0x0C
  { "interposing",              "S_INTERPOSING" },                // 0x0D
  { "16byte_literals",          "S_16BYTE_LITERALS" },            // 0x0E
  { 0, /*FIXME??*/              "S_DTRACE_DOF" },                 // 0x0F
  { 0, /*FIXME??*/              "S_LAZY_DYLIB_SYMBOL_POINTERS" }, // 0x10
  { "thread_local_regular",     "S_THREAD_LOCAL_REGULAR" },       // 0x11
  { "thread_local_zerofill",    "S_THREAD_LOCAL_ZEROFILL" },      // 0x12
  { "thread_local_variables",   "S_THREAD_LOCAL_VARIABLES" },     // 0x13
  { "thread_local_variable_pointers",
    "S_THREAD_LOCAL_VARIABLE_POINTERS" },                         // 0x14
  { "thread_local_init_function_pointers",
    "S_THREAD_LOCAL_INIT_FUNCTION_POINTERS"},                     // 0x15
```

Allowed `section attributes`:

```
ENTRY("pure_instructions",   S_ATTR_PURE_INSTRUCTIONS)
ENTRY("no_toc",              S_ATTR_NO_TOC)
ENTRY("strip_static_syms",   S_ATTR_STRIP_STATIC_SYMS)
ENTRY("no_dead_strip",       S_ATTR_NO_DEAD_STRIP)
ENTRY("live_support",        S_ATTR_LIVE_SUPPORT)
ENTRY("self_modifying_code", S_ATTR_SELF_MODIFYING_CODE)
ENTRY("debug",               S_ATTR_DEBUG)
ENTRY("" /*FIXME*/,          S_ATTR_SOME_INSTRUCTIONS)
ENTRY("" /*FIXME*/,          S_ATTR_EXT_RELOC)
ENTRY("" /*FIXME*/,          S_ATTR_LOC_RELOC)
```

Some examples:

```
//Variable in brand new segment & section, segment VM access defaults to read/write
int intInCustomPlace __attribute__ ( (section ("__DATA2,__data2") ));

//Read only string constant outside of __TEXT in readonly __LINKEDIT
char *kString __attribute__ ( (section ("__LINKEDIT,__customSection") )) = "value";
        
//C function in custom segment & section
void foo() __attribute__ ( (section ("__TEXT_EXEC,__customSection") ));

        
//obj-c method in custom section
@interface YourClass
- (void) foo:(NSInteger)someArg  __attribute__ ( (section ("__TEXT, __customSection") ));
@end

@interface YourClass ()
- (void) foo2:(NSInteger)someArg  __attribute__ ( (section ("__TEXT, __customSection") ));
@end
```

## [new] On function / method level using range

```
#pragma clang attribute push(__attribute__ ( (section ("__TEXT_EXEC,__customSection") )), apply_to=objc_method)
@interface AppDelegate ()
-(void)test;
-(void)test2;
@end

@interface AppDelegate ()
-(void)test3;
-(void)test4;
@end
#pragma clang attribute pop

#pragma clang attribute push(__attribute__ ( (section ("__TEXT,__customTextSection") )), apply_to=objc_method)
@interface AppDelegate
-(void)test5;
-(void)test6;
@end
#pragma clang attribute pop

#pragma clang attribute push(__attribute__ ( (section ("__TEXT_EXEC,__customSection") )), apply_to=function)
void func1();
void func2();
#pragma clang attribute pop
```

Bear in mind you can easily break stuff, `MachOView` is a convenient tool for inspecting your binary. Custom `("__TEXT,__cstring")` replacement would be most likely your best shot.

EDIT: A nonexisting segment by default will be emitted as readable & writeable (just like `__DATA`) so this won't work for executable code.

If you want explore the inline assembly path it's documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/Assembler/040-Assembler_Directives/asm_directives.html

Comment: The only issue with this is that I want to move every single variable from these sections into a separate segment without having to annotate every single one like this. Otherwise, I'll have thousands of places where I have to annotate it.

Comment: Can it can be renamed to __RODATA section?

Comment: The convention is uppercase denote segments (which may be composed of sections by convention in lowercase), so I assume you mean a `__RODATA` segment. Yes you can move some executable code to another segment (presumably from `__TEXT`) but you need to accommodate for adjusting the segment protection (`rx` in this case) for your `__RODATA`. By default linker would give it `rw` permissions.