# How to estimate the minimum memory usage of a process from the section information of a mach-o file?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, segment, mach-o

> App Size for iOS (& tvOS) only
>
> Your app’s total uncompressed size must be less than 4GB. Each Mach-O
> executable file (for example, app_name.app/app_name) must not exceed
> these limits:
>
> For apps whose MinimumOSVersion is less than 7.0: maximum of 80 MB for
> the total of all __TEXT sections in the binary.
> For apps whose
> MinimumOSVersion is 7.x through 8.x: maximum of 60 MB per slice for
> the __TEXT section of each architecture slice in the binary.
> For apps
> whose MinimumOSVersion is 9.0 or greater: maximum of 500 MB for the
> total of all __TEXT sections in the binary. However, consider download
> times when determining your app’s size. Minimize the file’s size as
> much as possible, keeping in mind that there is a 100 MB limit for
> over-the-air downloads.

Because Apple has requirements on the size of the __TEXT segment of the app, it is currently evaluating the code segment related information of our app, and is also analyzing whether there is unnecessary resident memory usage in our code.
I exported all the section data information of the app from the linkmap file here:

[image]

1. I know __TEXT is the code segment, it contain all the machine code which is compiled of my codes. so I guess all __TEXT sections must be loaded into memory, and long lived until the process exists.
   Is this view correct?
2. I notice that there are also __DATA segments and __RODATA segments, Do these segments also need to be all loaded into memory when the process is created?
3. If this view is correct, then the minimum amount of memory required by my process should at least also be larger than the sum of all these segment sizes right?
4. If I migrate some code that originally existed in __TEXT.__const to __DATA, will it help to reduce the memory footprint? (eg. change global const char*[] to char*[]).
5. If I can reduce the total size of __TEXT, __DATA, __RODATA, it will be helpful for the memory optimization of the app, right? Also make our App pass Apple's review?

Comment: For playing around with the executable you may find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/47951167/5329717

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I know __TEXT is the code segment, it contain all the machine code
>    which is compiled of my codes. so I guess all __TEXT sections must be
>    loaded into memory, and long lived until the process exists. Is this
>    view correct?

The machine code is actual the `__text` section of the `__TEXT` segment. Yes it has to be loaded in memory but not all at once, it is loaded page by page on demand. So when an instruction is going to be executed and it is not in memory it will trigger a page fault and a page (piece of code a few KB in size) that contains that instruction will be loaded.

> 2. I notice that there are also __DATA segments and __RODATA segments, Do these segments also need to be all loaded into memory when the
>    process is created?

The `__DATA` segment contains things like global variables (e.g. `var i = 1`), so they need to be loaded in memory. For `__RODATA` I am
not sure. These are loaded on demand also.

> 3.If this view is correct, then the minimum amount of memory required by
> my process should at least also be larger than the sum of all these
> segment sizes right?

Most of the times the memory needed for the dynamic data(arrays that are getting larger etc.) will be larger that the memory needs for the code, and this is the true limiting factor. Since the code is loaded on demand per page you can have a 500MB binary that only executes a 4KB piece of code, that will result in only 4KB of memory being used. Please note that the OS will unload old pages from memory to accommodate new ones. These old pages might be from other or the same program. If you have low memory the OS will constantly load and unload pages that will degrade performance.

> 4.If I migrate some code that originally existed in __TEXT.__const to __DATA, will it help to reduce the memory footprint? (eg. change global const char*[] to char*[]).

Not really.

> 5. If I can reduce the total size of __TEXT, __DATA, __RODATA, it will be helpful for the memory optimization of the app, right? Also make
>    our App pass Apple's review?

As long as you are under the Apple's limit for binary size you will pass the Apple's review. Reduce the size of __TEXT, __DATA, __RODATA can have an affect on performance, but their composition might be more important, like [Improving Locality of Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/CodeFootprint/Articles/ImprovingLocality.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001862-CJBJFIDD)