# Can I add additional sections to __TEXT segment with go linker?

Tags: macos, go, linker, ld

I use the `go` tool to compile and link my go programs.  I have a need to add additional sections to the `__TEXT` segment of Mach-O binaries produced this way.  Is it possible to do this?  For comparison, the standard BSD `ld` linker has a flag called `-sectcreate` (described on its [man page](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ld64/)) that allows the user to specify a file whose contents should be inserted into the binary in `__TEXT,section-name-you-specify`.  However, I'm not sure how to ask the `go` tool to do this, or whether it's even possible.

(Use case: daemons on Mac OS that run with root privileges have additional code-signing and identity requirements, specifically that new sections with names like `__info_plist` be added to the `__TEXT` segment with certain non-executable metadata content There's some background discussion of this [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/30309).)

I want to run my Go program as a privileged daemon on MacOS, but cannot see any way to add these additional sections when I compile with `go build`.

Comment: Your `go` tool would need to pass those params to `ld` linker anyway.  
Not an answer, but still this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47951167/5329717 could help you explore viable paths in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I was under the impression that `go` used its own linker, `cmd/link`, not the stock `ld` provided by the system.  (Source:  see Introduction section in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-ldflags-to-set-version-information-for-go-applications).  If the `go` tool is in fact using the system's stock `ld` program, then the answer to my question is just to pass some arguments as `go build -ldflags=....` and it should work today with the current `go` tool.  Does anyone know what linker `go build` uses?