clang on MacOS does not honor -ffunction-sections
On linux, clang, following gcc, has a -ffunction-sections option that causes each function to be put in its own separate section (then one can use appropriate linking options to cause unused sections, thus unused functions, to be removed).
Yet, it seems that clang silently ignores this option on MacOS: the assembly code is identical with or without it.
Is this normal? Any comment?

Not sure if it helps, but on MacOS (and iOS) you can control individual function section using clang attributes in code. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47951167/5329717

Remark number one, this behaviour does not happen with Apple clang when targeting linux (and thus generating an ELF object instead of a Mach-O object).
It looks like the TEXT segment is only meant to include a finite set of sections according to https://github.com/aidansteele/osx-abi-macho-file-format-reference

__TEXT,__text
__TEXT,__cstring
__TEXT,__picsymbol_stub
__TEXT,__symbol_stub
__TEXT,__const
__TEXT,__literal4
__TEXT,__literal8

Consequently, while the driver should probably emit some sort of diagnostic, it is probably a consequence of the output binary format not supporting the option.
